# Freemarker and JSP without MVC

Tags: freemarker

I got a website without any MVC but plain old JSP and some inline classes. (calling the page like index.jsp)
For testing purpose, I can make freemarker works on a single jsp file. like configuration, create data model and template.process in the same page.

My problem is i don't know how to implement freemarker for the whole site.
like do the configuration once?
get the same configuration instance in every jsp? so i can get template and process

additionally, I heard <@include_page path="path/to/some.jsp"/> only works with FreemarkerServlet. i wonder if I can use this feature in my case.

i did google and like every results are related to servlet and mvc stuff.
hope somebody here can give me some idea. T

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have only one `Configuration` instance per purpose (like web page rendering is one purpose, e-mail rendering is another); that's crucial for performance. If you are calling FreeMarker from a JSP page (if I understand that well), you could put the initialized `Configuration` object in to an application scoped attribute (a.k.a. `SerlvetContext` attribute).

`@include_page` is custom directive provided by the `FreemarkerServlet`. However, it's just a custom directive, and you could write another one by implementing `TemplateDirectiveModel`. The tricky part is to pass servlet-related objects (like the current request) to it. Usually, you should put a custom attribute into the `freemarker.core.Environment` object (see in its API), and then since the `TemplateDirectiveModel` receives the `Environment` as a parameter, it can read out that custom attribute from it.